# What's the inverse of the gradient of a gradient?

Tags: inverse, tensors

I am wondering if, for a given functio $f(\mathbf{x})$, there exists a tensor $\mathbf{A}$ such that $$\nabla \nabla f \cdot \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}$$ To make it clearer, in index notation (with summation convention). $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} A_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$$ What conditions does $f$ have to satisfy for the inverse to exhist?

Comment: In general, it does exist.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In general, $f$ is not twice differentiable...

Comment: @Federico: why not ??? (By the way, the question implicitly assumes that the Hessian exists.)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "in general". There are precise ways to formalize that the "majority" of functions are note differentiable (at any point), for instance Baire category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "gradient of a gradient" $\nabla^2 f$ is the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) of F. In order for $A$ to exist, you are asking the Hessian to be invertible. This is the case for instance if $f$ is $\lambda$-convex with $\lambda>0$ (this is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions) calls strongly convex).